# Unable to access the database after MySQL `wait_timeout` exceeded

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, c3p0

**This question is not duplicate. This clearly identifies the issue is due to mysql_timeout while the other post is not.  The other post seems to have config items which I might not need at all. In the other post the poster managed to run the app by adding lot of other config code which I haven't seen in applications too****

I have a web application developed with pure JSP and Servlet, using `HIbernate` and `c3p0` as well. It is using `MySQL` as the database. There is a problem in my application, that is, whenever the `wait_timeout` is exceeded, the application is throwing the below exception.

```
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2066)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1863)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1839)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:497)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
    at dao.SubuserImpl.findByName(SubuserImpl.java:87)
    at service.SubuserService.findSubuserByName(SubuserService.java:199)
    at controller.login.LoginChkSrvlt.processRequest(LoginChkSrvlt.java:51)
    at controller.login.LoginChkSrvlt.doPost(LoginChkSrvlt.java:137)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 499,241 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 1 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1129)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3720)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4160)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2617)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2778)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2834)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2156)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2313)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3166)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3620)
    ... 48 more
```

I confirmed the issue is due to the expiry of mysql `wait_timeout` by setting it to a low value (it is normally set to 8 hours).

I have configured the c3p0 in the configuration file like below.

```
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxx</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin">true</property>
```

How I can solve this issue? I know I can solve this by adding the `auto-reconnect` to the JDBC url, but it is not recommended.

Comment: Did you take a look at the answers? Did you try out the suggestions? I have faced this issue twice and the root cause has always been the same.

Comment: @ChetanKinger: He has solved it by adding lot of other config details. And it was a GWT application.

Comment: Did you try the suggestions? Why is adding config details a problem? GWT or not, hibernate is hibernate.

Comment: @ChetanKinger: what are the suggestions? to use `hibernate.c3p0.automaticTestTable`? it is not working at all.

Comment: Might your application be holding Connections (or hibernate Sessions) open, rather than acquiring them on demand and closing them promptly (as it should)?

Comment: @SteveWaldman: all the hibernate sessions are closed once they are used. Is there a way to tell the applycation to "auto reconnect" ? This line ` <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout" value="true" />` could do it but application is generating errors on adding it.

Comment: @JustCause there is an `autoconnect=true` setting you can add to the JDBC URL. that's fine to add, but c3p0 should be observing and killing expired Connections as well. i just took another look at your config settings. it looked like you were using testConnectionOnCheckin and idleConnectionTestPeriod, which is a reasonable combo, but your idleConnectionTestPeriod is way, way too long if you are not testing on checkout. Should be on the order of 30 secs. See http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_connection_testing

Comment: @JustCause setting `<property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout" value="true" />` is a good idea, the first thing you should do is turn off all other Connection testing and try that alone for simplicity. If that is causing errors, it should not, let's debug those.

Comment: @SteveWaldman: I actually got most of it from the mkyong's website.

Comment: @SteveWaldman: OK, Can you please tell me what I have to remove before adding the code you mentioned?

Comment: just drop both `<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>` and  `<property name="testConnectionOnCheckin">true</property>` and use `<property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout" value="true" />` instead. Bu also... ooops! You needed that second property in your current config to be  `<property name="*hibernate.c3p0.*testConnectionOnCheckin">true</property>`, right now it isn't doing anything. But I'd start with just  `<property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout" value="true" />`

Comment: @JustCause (the asterixes surrounding *hibernate.c3p0* in the comment above were intended as bold, please don't literally include the asterixes in your config... :)

Comment: @JustCause btw, what version of c3p0 are you using? if you are using any version prior to c3p0-0.9.5 (and/or if you are using an older JDBC driver), please be sure to supply an efficient preferredTestQuery, something like `<property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">SELECT 1</property>`

Comment: @SteveWaldman: Hi, I Can't add that line, I am getting the error `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 15; columnNumber: 57; Attribute "value" must be declared for element type "property".`

Comment: Which line? Keep the syntax consistent with the rest of the properties in your config file, ie we've mixed two styles in our conversation, `<property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout" value="true" />` and `<property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">true</property>` but in reality you'll need to use one style consistently.

Comment: @SteveWaldman: Tried everything, lot of things, still in the same place.

Comment: You can't even get testConnectionOnCheckout to configure?

Comment: @SteveWaldman: I tried them all, but the timeout issue is remaining :( I read somewhere that we have to configure c3p0 in a separate file. You know how to do it?

Comment: yes, i wrote the library. but you shouldn't need to, configuring from within hibernate should be fine. c3p0 logs its confit at INFO on pool initialization. you should check there and make sure the data source is configured as you expect (and maybe add that config dump to your question)

Comment: (i gotta sleep now, so it'll be a while before i can get back to you.)

Comment: @SteveWaldman: You wrote which library?

Comment: @SteveWaldman: Wait, you wrote c3p0 ? Damn, that is amazing!

Comment: (it'd be more amazing if it were working for you!)

Comment: @SteveWaldman: Yeah, sure. I will see more here what I can do to fix it as well.

Comment: (oh, btw, a kind of failsafe you can try for connection timeout issues is the config param maxConnectionAge. you should get testing working, bc Connections can fail for reasons other than timeouts. but maxConnectionAge can ensure you never hit timeouts if you want.)

Comment: @SteveWaldman: OK, Let me try that too. I have to wait for 2 mins. Because I have changed the connection time out to 8 hours to 2.

Comment: @SteveWaldman: I can't see any parameter called `maxConnectionAge `

Comment: with a 2 min timeout, you'll have to set maxConnectionAge to ~60 secs to ensure it is enforced promptly enough. with a more reasonable timeout, you won't have to leave a 50% margin of safety.

Comment: @SteveWaldman: In netbeans, the `maxConnectionAge` is not getting diaplayed?

Comment: http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#maxConnectionAge

Comment: no idea abt netbeans. should be accessible via jmx. you'd set it as hibernate.c3p0.maxConnectionAge

Comment: @SteveWaldman: May be not available in my c3p0 version? I am using the default one which came with the latest hibernate version...

Comment: no, it'd have to be a really old version to lack maxConnectionAge. but you should upgrade to 0.9.5. the c3p0 version is logged at INFO, just before the config dump.

Comment: tried maxConnectionAge, still no good. restarting the tomcat...

Comment: So for all this config-ing, we've missed something basic. There's no indication from the Exception stack trace above that c3p0 is even being used. if it's not, obviously configuring c3p0 Connection testing and expiration params can't help. Do you see any indication in your logs that c3p0 is being used?

Comment: @SteveWaldman how to find it? However I believe the issue is now solved, because after adding all the 3 libs provided by hibernate inside c3p0 folder and following your advice, I didn't see the issue.... but I have to check again and again..